# Alitalia changed flight made our travel impossible

Tags: air-travel, alitalia

Alitalia changed the second flight of my connection, making it impossible for me to travel between Ajaccio (AJA) and Rome (FCO). The new scheduled flight leaves a day before we even take our first flight. Since our flight date has been changed and not cancelled, am I still eligible for a refund? Ive just now received the email announcing the change and the flight was supposed to take place next thursday. [image: The flight info provided on Alitalia's website]

Comment: This is clearly a mistake, have you Alitalia to ask them to correct it yet?

Comment: Usually when such a thing happens they will automatically change the second flight as well, or get in touch. That can take a few hours/days though. Better to be proactive and call them. Better yet, check your options to see what you want to get (and/or what you definitely don’t want).

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.